# Какого рода слово «судья»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, существительные, род

А именно в контексте, когда речь идет о женщине. Вчера смотрела передачу, там показывали женщину и в титре написали "бывший судья".
Разве применительно к женщине все равно нужно говорить в мужском роде? Разве не ***бывшая** судья*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С существительными общего рода не следует путать существительные, которые обозначают лиц по профессии, роду занятий. Например: доцент, агроном, профессор, судья, космонавт и многие другие. В грамматическом отношении эти существительные не стали существительными общего рода, сохранили свою принадлежность к мужскому роду. Поэтому прилагательные с такими существительными согласуются только в форме мужского рода. Например: новый судья Иванова, известный скульптор Мухина. А вот сказуемые при таких существительных могут находиться как в форме мужского рода, так и в форме женского рода. Например: новый судья Иванов вынес решение. Или: в выставке участвовала известный скульптор Мухина. 
http://interneturok.ru/ru/school/russian/6-klass/bglava-3b/imena-suschestvitelnye-obschego-roda

Comment: Людмила, а что это за источник такой?  
Я не хотел влезать в терминологический спор по поводу отнесения профессий к общему роду, пусть будет отдельная категория, не суть.
Но *всякое* запрещение при таких словах прилагательных в женском роде = это нм в какие ворота не лезет.

https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%22+

430К вхождений.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то заголовок вопроса не соответствует тексту. 
Ответ на вопрос в заголовке таков. *Слово "судья" - т.н. общего рода*. Тут, правда, может встать вопрос систематики, ибо называют по-разному, но, думаю, в данной теме эти споры не столь существенны, суть понятна.

А вот вопрос о том, как называть "бывшего судью" или "бывшую судью" придется разбирать глубже. Мало того, что "неправильный" род - признак разговорного стиля. Дело еще в том, что большинство таких слов имеют весьма ограниченную область сочетания с женским родом (а какие-то, возможно - с мужским). Можно сказать "наша врач", с большим сомнением - "заслуженная врач", и нет никаких вариантов для "(видел) практикующую врача". Короче, судья - она только в контекстах, где важно показать пол и только в именительном падеже. В остальных случаях подобная вольность, вроде бы, невозможна.

Так что, похоже, в передаче сказали правильно.

Answer (score 0):

В передаче всё правильно. Надо говорить "наш врач Иванова", "опытный следователь Петрова", но "Петя такой неряха", "Наташа такая неряха".

Answer (score -1):

В русской грамматике четыре категории рода. Это мужской, женский, средний и парный. Основным грамматическим признаком определения рода является определение по рядом стоящему слову, чаще всего с помощью части речи, обозначающей признак предмета (адьектив). Ср. РИМСКИЙ папа, КОНСТИТУЦИОННЫЙ судья и т.п.